# Chrome: font size of tabs, bookmarks' bar etc

Tags: fonts, chrome, user-interface

Depending on the DPI settings, the fonts used in the Chrome user interface may be the wrong size, because Chrome (2018.07.22) respects the DPI settings when it renders web pages' content, but not when it draws the UI.

E.g., my 13.3", 1366x768 display has approximately 118 DPI both in the horizontal and the vertical direction  and when I use that value a 12pt font in a web page is, approximately, 12 points on my screen but the font in the UI is a bit largish, the bookmarks' bar is truncated and the tabs are a bit crowded.

Chromium developers made clear that changing the font of the UI is not something they're going to support, I see that it is possible to circumvent the problem on Windows, what can be done on Linux?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older post.  The Chrome UI font size can usually be changed by changing the fixed-width font size if you are in a GTK environment.  If you are in KDE Plasma you have to change the GNOME/GTK Application Style.  You can find this setting under Application Style in System Settings.

Comment: Hi Shane, I'm using an environment _sui generis_ and I cannot test your answer but, are you sure that changing GTK's **fixed-width** font size can modify the size of the UI font in Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

On Gnome 1.43, I was able to use the "Tweaks" app to scale all UI fonts (go to Fonts | scaling factor), then reduce the size of the standard text (same dialog) to compensate. Doing this, I can get about equal-sized fonts in the address bar and the tabs/bookmarks with a little customizing in chrome's font sizes as well. I had to adjust several other apps to compensate for scaling also, so this may not be an easy fix.